# $node->form_id doesn't exist?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node){
    if($node->form_id == 'whatever_node_form'){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Returns an error: 
`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$form_id in mymodule_node_insert() (line 16 of /home/admin/public_html/website.com/sites/all/modules/mystuff/mystull.module).`

I can clearly see the array dump of $node that it is indeed an object and it contains form_id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks right and this is what I have in my similar functions -- is it finding the form you want it to and just throwing an error condition because of a high PHP error level?

Comment: Hah, no, figured it out... I was creating another node inside this function, and it was calling hook_node_insert a second time, recursively, and leaving out form_id. So what looked like the right array was actually NOT the correct output! Gah.

Comment: If it's not a property added by another module, `$node->form_id` is not a property added by Drupal.

Comment: This is a localized questions that doesn't help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is actually correct. When checking for an object, it's always a good idea to use `isset()` to make sure the variable exists!

This code was adjusted to the following:

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node){
  if (isset($node->form_id) && ($node->form_id == 'whatever_node_form')) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```